# Axios throws Network error on POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, axios

Use axios to do a post to a ASP.NET WEB API controller . Below is the code. I am able to make a call to "get" but when i do a post i get a network error.

[image]

If i change the Content-Type to "**x-www-form-urlencoded**" i am able to make a call but the posted json data is not posted . PLease find also WEB API code

```
const defReqConfig = Axios.defaults;
        defReqConfig.method = "post";
        defReqConfig.baseURL = "http://localhost:16755/api/v1/";
        defReqConfig.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
        const axiosServiceInstance: AxiosInstance = Axios.create(defReqConfig);
        return axiosServiceInstance.post("author/pd", postData)
```

c# web api code

```
[Route("pd")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Author pq)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, pq);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the Developers Tool Network tab what is error status code you get POST call is initiated? Also, please share how postData variable is populated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it to working with setting the transform for it 
this.baseURL = "http://localhost:16755/api/v1/";
        this.transformRequest = (data: any, headers: any) => {
            const serializedData = []
            for (const k in data) {
                if (data[k]) {
                    serializedData.push(`${k}=${encodeURIComponent(data[k])}`)
                }
            }
            return serializedData.join('&')
        }